# Leitura de Arquivo com Inteiros e Strings em C

Tags: c

Preciso ler um arquivo com dados em que um número inteiro é o ID do produto em uma linha, o nome do produto na linha seguinte e o autorizador do produto na linha seguinte ao nome do produto. Totalizando 3 linhas para cada produto.

Exemplo do arquivo Txt com 3 produtos:

```
7891058005221  
AMARYL 4MG  
SANOFI – PROGRAMA VIVA  FUNCIONAL  
7896015529086  
ANORO  
VIVER MAIS – GSK    FUNCIONAL  
7896637017046  
ARPADOL 60CP  
PROGRAMA SOU MAIS VIDA – APSEN  FUNCIONAL
```

Quero que o usuário entre com o código em Números e o programa ache o produto e escreva o nome do produto e o programa ao qual ele pertence.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
struct Item{
    int EAN;
    char Medicamento[30];
    char Programa[100];
};
main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");

    struct Item Item;
    bool achou = false;
    int EAN_P;
    char Buscador[30];
    FILE *BancoMed;

    BancoMed = fopen("BancoMed.txt","r");

    if(BancoMed == NULL)
        {
            printf("\n Erro ao abrir! ");
            close();
        }

    do{
        printf("\n Código de barra / 0 para sair: ");
        scanf("%d",&EAN_P);

        do
        {
            fscanf(BancoMed,"%d\n",&Item.EAN);
            if(Item.EAN == EAN_P)
                achou = true;
            fgets(Item.Medicamento,"%s",BancoMed);
            fgets(Item.Programa,"%s",BancoMed);


        }while(fgets(Buscador,"%s",BancoMed)!=NULL && achou!=true );

        printf("\n %s\n %s",Item.Medicamento,Item.Programa);

    }while(EAN_P!=0);

    fclose(BancoMed);
}
```

O problema é que ele imprime o último item, nunca o do meio ou o primeiro.

Comment: Você está especificando os parâmetros da função fgets de forma errada. Os parâmetros são: Ponteiro para um array de char para onde será lida a string; Número máximo de caracteres a serem copiados; Ponteiro para um objeto do tipo FILE.

Comment: Não acredito que o problema esteja ali, pois mesmo mudando o parâmetro de quantidade de Char ele ainda não consegue passar pela condicional, ele lê até o final do arquivo e imprime sempre os últimas 3 linhas (ID, Produto e Autorizador)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema Resolvido

```
do
        {
            fscanf(BancoMed,"%d\n",&Item.EAN);
            if(Item.EAN == EAN_P)
            {
                fgets(Item.Medicamento,"%s",BancoMed);
                fgets(Item.Programa,"%s",BancoMed);
                break;
            }
        }while(fgets(Buscador,"%s",BancoMed)!=NULL && achou!=true );
```

No bloco do-while onde testa se eu achei o ID , eu fiz um bloco onde caso ele ache o ID em inteiros e compare ao pedido ele armazena as strings necessárias.

Comment: Onde você colocou este "%s" você tem que colocar o número máximo de caracteres a serem lidos. Consulte a documentação da função fgets.

Comment: Então, como comentei acima, esse não era o problema, pois mesmo usando o parâmetro de Ler string "%s",  funciona normalmente capturando as strings necessária para o objetivo do programa. Mesmo assim obrigado pela atenção.